# Why is this transformation's standard matrix the way it is?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I know for a simple rotation of $2$ vectors, I know that the vector $\left[\begin{matrix}1\\0\end{matrix}\right]$ rotates to $\left[\begin{matrix}\cos\phi\\\sin\phi\end{matrix}\right]$ and the vector $\left[\begin{matrix}0\\1\end{matrix}\right]$ rotates to $\left[\begin{matrix}-\sin\phi\\\cos\phi\end{matrix}\right]$. But why? I can see geometrically why the first vector rotates to where it does, but the second vector? Why? It just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: In addition to the answer by Arkamis, you might be interested in reading [*Wiki - Rotations*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\cos(\phi + \pi/2) = -\sin(\phi)$$

---

In other words, $[0\ 1]^T$ is $[1\ 0]^T$ rotated by $\pi/2$.

Using the trig identity

$$\cos(u+v) = \cos u \cos v - \sin u \sin v$$

with $u = \phi$ and $v = \pi/2$, we have

$$\cos(\phi+\pi/2) = \cos \phi \cos \pi/2 - \sin \phi \sin \pi / 2 = 0 - 1\cdot \sin \phi$$

Comment: Ah I see why that is now... I had a feeling it would be something fairly simple

Answer (score 2):

The image of the first vector tells you that it is the rotation $+\phi$ with the usual counterclockwise orientation.

So
$$
\left(\matrix{0\\1} \right)=\left(\matrix{\cos(\pi/2)\\\sin(\pi/2)} \right)\longmapsto \left(\matrix{\cos(\pi/2+\phi )\\ \sin(\pi/2+\phi)} \right)=\left(\matrix{-\sin(\phi)\\\cos(\phi)} \right).
$$